# Can I save 2 entries to my models that are referencing each other?

Tags: python, django, django-models, cs50

I have 2 models, "Listing" and "Bid"
Bids:

```
# bids and bidder
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(default=10) #default soll durch user gesetzt werden

    # Foreign Keys
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bids")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bids")
```

Listing:

```
# all information related to a listing
class Listing(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24848110/33519396-7e56363c-d79d-11e7-969b-09782f5ccbab.png")
    bid = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    auction_open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # Foreign Keys
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
```

place_bid():

```
def place_bid(request, listing_id):
    bidder = request.user
    bid = request.POST.get("bid")

    listing_entry = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)

    bid_entry = Bid(listing=listing_entry, bid=bid, bidder=bidder)
    bid_entry.save()

    listing_entry.bid = bid_entry

    listing_entry.save()

    return;
```

In a function "place_bid()" I want to create a new "Bid"-instance that references a already existing "Listing"-instance using a foreign key.
The problem arrises because of what I want to do next: I want to change the same "Listing"-instance that was just referenced, I want to replace the "Bid" object of that Listing object to that "Bid"-object I just created.
Can you please help me out there:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from your description, I understood each Bid has a listing but also that each listing only has 1 Bid. If that is the case I would recommend switching the definition of the field to OneToOneField instead of a ForiegnKey.

```
def place_bid(request, listing_id):
    bidder = request.user
    bid = request.POST.get("bid")

    listing_entry = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)

    # Here there is a small problem with your current models setup because each listing
    # can have several Bids. Here is a small patch for now. But I recommend that you change that to:
    # listing_entry.bid if you do chose to use OneToOneField there instead
    bid = listing_entry.bids.first()
    bid.update(listing=listing_entry, bid=bid, bidder=bidder)
    bid.save()

    return # no need for that: ;
```